# Load a webpage in an app? Or load data from a server?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-webview

My Android Studio java app has several KB of 3rd party pricing data (postage prices) hard coded in, and when the prices change I'd just update the app (normally this is only once or twice a year).

The last update took 3 weeks for Google Play to roll out, when I designed the app it would roll out in a day or two.

I need to update the pricing data much faster, so I'm thinking of making the app just load a webpage from my server

- Pro: pricing can be updated instantly, plus if the 3rd party do unexpected changes I can redesign the webpage quickly. I'm also more experienced at HTML / JavaScript than java.
- Con: it'd need internet access, and may cause a slight delay getting the prices.

Another option would be to fetch the data from my server and store it on the phone. At the moment I'm using SharedPreferences to store tiny amounts of data, not sure if it's wise to store several KB's of data in SharedPreferences.

- Pro: can still get up-to date prices, and if the phone is offline it can use the pricing data from the last time it was online.
- Con: Unexpected changes might still need an app update (eg. last year the postage company surprisingly created extra postal zones)

Question:
what would be the best way to make an app access a webpage, a quick google makes me think using WebView is suitable?

If it's best to save several KB of data on the device, is it still ok to use SharedPreferences, or should I be using something else? App specific storage - getFilesDir?
What's the best way of downloading the data from my server to the device?

Comment: You put a file on your server with all the prices. At every start of your app you check if there is a new file and if so download it to getFilesDir(). We will not discuss things like the best way. For all this WebView cannot be used. Dont place your prices in a html file. Why did you?

Answer (score 0):

> Question: what would be the best way to make an app access a webpage,
> a quick google makes me think using WebView is suitable?

Very simple way to show website is to use vebView without building activity for it.

example:

```
public void openMyWeb() {
    try {
        activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("https://google.com")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Replace "**https://google.com**" with your own web address.  I has to start with https://  Note that it will trow exception on Console play virtual test machines unless you catch it.